# Bootstrap dynamic button width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I have a row on a webpage that is going to display a list of buttons. The width of the button needs to be dynamic because it is going
to be filled with words inputed by a user. Also, once the combined width
of all the buttons on the row is equal to the width of the column, I want subsequent buttons to be displayed on the next line. Here's my HTML:

```
     <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class="col-xs-4 btn-group" role="group" align='center' id="actualList" style="margin-right:50px; visibility:hidden;">
            <h3>Possible words:</h3>
            <div class="list-group" id="wordList">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">button</button>
            </div>    
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

The width of the buttons is dynamic when I try it on JSfiddle, but for
some reason it isn't working in my code. I think the rows are messing things up. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

So I figured out what was messing it up. In my custom style sheet, I make some changes to the .btn class. I need the custom style for another portion of my site. Is there a way to ignore the my styles sheet just for this list?

Comment: Post the JSFiddle link.

Comment: So I figured out what was messing it up. In my custom style sheet, I make some changes to the .btn class. I need the custom style for another portion of my site. Is there a way to ignore the my styles sheet just for this list?

Comment: Yes there is, using :not (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp).

Answer (score 1):

> So I figured out what was messing it up. In my custom style sheet, I
>   make some changes to the .btn class. I need the custom style for
>   another portion of my site. Is there a way to ignore the my styles
>   sheet just for this list?

One good way would be to add a wrapper selector to the part where you are customizing your .btn class. Something like

```
.myOtherSitePortion .btn {
    /* .btn customizations */
}
```

Then for the pages that you need the custom style applied just add the class `myOtherSitePortion`, like so

```
<body class="myOtherSitePortion">
     ....
     <input class="btn"...
```

I'm assuming you don't need the custom style on the page where you need the dynamic bootstrap width. If yes, just move the class to a parent element that includes the button you want to customize but excludes the portion where you need the dynamic bootstrap width.